# Чем отличается блок виджета календаря от календаря событий как плагин?

Tags: wordpress

Это было написано в официально документации, но суть не раскрыта.

> The Calendar Widget block does not let you create a calendar of
> events. For that, you need an Events calendar plugin.

*Перевод:*

> Блок виджета календаря не позволяет создавать календарь событий. Для
> этого вам нужен плагин календаря событий.

Хочется прояснить момент, а чем же все таки отличаются блок виджета календаря и календарь событий как плагин.

Что Wordpress подразумевает в документации под "календарем событий", если они предупреждают что их решение не подходит.

Мне кажется эта тема не раскрыта, либо я не увидел дополнительных ссылок на разъяснение что есть что.

Comment: Никаких "событий" в ВП нет. Есть записи. Поэтому не может быть и "календаря событий". Есть "календарь записей". Установи плагины календарей событий и всё поймёшь. Или хотя бы почитай их описание.

Comment: Установите [The Events Calendar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/) например, и станет ясно